# ASP.NET MVC in "web site project"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that can co-exists with web form no problem as Hanselman mention [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).  However, we current have a "Web Site" project.  I am just wondering if MVC would work in this kind of project instead of web application.

Comment: WAG:  Probably, but it'll be a pain in the ass to set it up and maintain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I never did it and will recommend it, I find an [interesting post](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx) here. It seems doable.